Starting Gazebo Harmonic fro the first time QThread error
Hello im a noobie strating learning ROS2 and Gazebo sim.
I follow the instalation via ROS2 official instalation, and the command:
sudo apt-get install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-gz

And the instalation goes succesfully, however when i start gz, with:
gz sim

It starts the Gazebo menu, but with this message on the terminal:
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread

And when i want to start a demo simulation, it gets on a loop, and never starts the simulation.
This is the log of gz:
~/.gz$ cat *.log

(2024-10-13T15:43:30.661578587) (2024-10-13T15:43:30.661600050) [Dbg] [gz.cc:166] Subscribing t(2024-10-13T15:43:30.663028484) (2024-10-13T15:43:30.663040338) [Msg] Gazebo Sim Quick start dialog
(2024-10-13T15:43:30.793845747) (2024-10-13T15:43:30.793870874) [Dbg] [Application.cc:96] Initializing application.
(2024-10-13T15:43:30.793960999) (2024-10-13T15:43:30.793968936) [Dbg] [Application.cc:170] Qt using OpenGL graphics interface
(2024-10-13T15:43:30.870410824) (2024-10-13T15:43:30.870423923) [GUI] [Dbg] [Gui.cc:142] Reading Quick start menu config.
(2024-10-13T15:43:36.927874118) (2024-10-13T15:43:36.927911440) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] qrc:/Gazebo/QuickStart.qml:236: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-10-13T15:43:36.977944341) (2024-10-13T15:43:36.977981360) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:908] [QT] qrc:/Gazebo/QuickStart.qml:236: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
...
...
...
